# 301 redirect from apache - can headers be preserved?

Tags: apache

I want to redirect from a folder to another server to take some load off of an apache site. On the site there are some security measures which look at various request headers to determine whether or not a given request is valid. When I forward these using a 'redirect 301' these headers are being replaced with those of the existing server (instead of the server that the original request came from).

Is there a way to use mod_alias or mod_redirect to return a 301 and forward all the original headers to the new site?